# Synchronise a method different Sidekiq threads and wait

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading, google-ads-api, sidekiq

**Problem:**
I have several sidekiq threads and a function that may only be called once at the time from any of the threads.

**Reason:**
We are querying the AdWords API to get some data. They are quite restrictive when it comes to rate limits. Only one of the threads may call the function to get data at a time.

**Now some code:**

```
# Public: Get estimates for a set of keywords. If there is an error, retry
# several times. If not successful, raise an error
#
# keywords: The keyword objects to get estimates for.
# save: Boolean to indicate whether the keyword objects should be saved to
# the database
#
def repeatedly_try_get_estimates(keywords: [], save: true, sleep_delay: 150)
  return keywords if keywords.empty?
  func = -> { get_estimates(keywords, !save) }
  retry_operation(function: func, max_tries: 15, sleep_delay: sleep_delay)
end
```

- As you can see, right now I have a huge `sleep_delay` work around the problem.
- The code calls the `retry_operation` function with the
  `get_estimates` function as parameter. It will then retry the
  `get_estimates` function several times until there is an API
  exception.

The `retry_function`:

```
# Private: Retry a function X times and wait X seconds. If it does not work X times,
# raise an error. If successful return the functions results.
#
# - max_tries: The maximum tries to repeat the function
# - sleep_delay: The seconds to wait between each iteration.
# - function: The lambda function to call each iteration
#
def retry_operation(max_tries: 5, sleep_delay: 30, function: nil, current_try: 0, result: nil)

  # Can't call, no function
  if function.nil?
    return
  end

  # Abort, tried too frequently.
  if current_try > max_tries
    raise "Failed function too often"
  end

  # Check if there is an exception
  exception = true
  begin
    result = function.call
    exception = false
  rescue => e
    Rails.logger.info "Received error when repeatedly calling function #{e.message.to_s}"
  end

  if exception
    sleep sleep_delay if sleep_delay > 0
    retry_operation(max_tries: max_tries, sleep_delay: sleep_delay, function: function, current_try: current_try + 1)
  else
    result
  end
end
```

The `get_estimates_function` is here: https://gist.github.com/a14868d939ef0e34ef9f. It is too long, just in case.

**I guess I need to do the following:**

1. Adjust the code in the `repeatedly_try_get_estimates` function.
2. Use a mutex in the class.
3. Rescue the exception if the mutex is in use.
4. Only if the mutex is free, run the `rety_operation`, else sleep some time

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Are you using only one sidekiq process with multiple threads or is there more than one sidekiq process running?

Comment: It is a single sidekiq process, with multiple threads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here we go, got it to work:

```
# Public: Get estimates for a set of keywords. If there is an error, retry
# several times. If not successful, raise an error
#
# keywords: The keyword objects to get estimates for.
# save: Boolean to indicate whether the keyword objects should be saved to
# the database
#
def repeatedly_try_get_estimates(keywords: [], save: true, sleep_delay: 40)
  return keywords if keywords.empty?
  func = -> { get_estimates(keywords, save_keywords: true) }
  exception = nil
  result = nil
  initial_sleep = 0

  estimates_mutex.synchronize do
    since_last_request = Time.now.to_i - last_adwords_api_request
    if since_last_request <= 30
      Rails.logger.info "AdWords: Last request was only few seconds ago - sleeping #{since_last_request}."
      initial_sleep = since_last_request
    end
    begin
      result = retry_operation(function: func, max_tries: 15, sleep_delay: sleep_delay, initial_sleep: initial_sleep)
    rescue => e
      exception = e
    end
    @@last_adwords_api_request = Time.now.to_i
  end
  if exception
    raise exception
  end
  result
end
```